# Cross domain access using jQuery, YQL

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, yql

I am sure this question has been asked many a times but I just can't figure out what is wrong with my code..

I am trying to access careerbuilder's api to get job listings in San Jose. The request executes with a response code of 200 (OK) however, I am not able to view any response.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var url2use="http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=WDHS54569PZ5S5SPPVHH&BooleanOperator=OR&CountryCode=US&Keywords=student,part-time,intern&Radius=30&PerPage=50&Location=San Jose, Santa Clara";

          var yqlUrl2use = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+"q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+encodeURIComponent(url2use)+
        "%22&format=xml&callback=?";
        $.ajax({
                     url: yqlUrl2use,
                     dataType: "html",
                     type: "GET",
                     success: function(xml) {
                 var myXML = xml.responseText;
                // what i want to do with results
                                 }

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `dataType: "json"`?

Also, you have one too many close parentheses `}`

And lastly, you receive an object with an array of results, so instead of:

```
var myXML = xml.responseText;
```

Use:

```
var myXML = xml.results[0];
```

I'm sorry but other than those tips, I couldn't get the request to work. It does work but for some reason YQL won't return the right results (even if you try it in the YQL console)